# delete directories with find and exclude other directories

Tags: find

I'm attempting to delete some directories and I want to be able to exclude a directory called 'logs' from being deleted.

This is my basic find operation (without the exclusion):

```
# find . -type d  |tail -10
./d20160124-1120-df8mfb/deployments
./d20160124-1120-df8mfb/releases
./d20160131-16993-vazqg5
./d20160131-16993-vazqg5/metadata
./d20160131-16993-vazqg5/deployments
./d20160131-16993-vazqg5/releases
./logs
./d20160203-27735-1tqbjh6
./d20160125-1120-1yccr9p
./d20160131-16993-1yf9lnc
```

I'm just tailing the output so that you have an idea of what's going on without taking up the whole page. :)

If I try to exlclude the logs directory with the prune command I get back no results.

```
root@ops-manager:/tmp/tmp# find . -type d  -prune -o -name 'logs' -print
root@ops-manager:/tmp#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Once I get this right, I'll tack on an -exec rm rf {} \; command so I can delete those directories.

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: Must the solution be in pure bash? If so, it would be a good idea putting the `bash` tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`-prune` always evaluates to true, which means the expression on the other side of `-o` is never evaluated. You need to change the order:

```
find . -type d -name 'logs' -prune -o -print
```